# Continuing a long running process in the background under iOS4

Tags: ios

I have have an upload queue running using ASIHTTP request. When the user presses the home screen and the app goes into the background I would like this operation to continue. From the documentation I can see how I would call a new task could be called to run in the back ground, but can't quite see how I would flag an already running task to continue.

Answer (score 2):

this example is bracketed for pre-4.0 compatibility:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
if ([app respondsToSelector:@selector(beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)]) {
    backgroundTaskIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (backgroundTaskIdentifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
            {
                // you took too long - clean up what you can, then …
                [app endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifier];
                backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    }];
}

// start HTTP request …
```

when you complete your process, you should call `endBackgroundTask:` to let the app know

Comment: Also try adding     
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier __block backgroundTaskIdentifier; 
before this block. :)