# Running a long process in the background in iOS5 and above

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, background-process

I have have an download queue running using ASIHTTP request. When the user presses the home screen and the app goes into the background I would like this operation to continue. I know that ASIHTTP request can run in the background, but I want the process that runs the ASIHTTP request to run in background as well.

How do i do it?

I saw this post in StackOverflow: [Continuing a long running process in the background under iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430781/continuing-a-long-running-process-in-the-background-under-ios4)

But the solution is in iOS4. I would like to do it in iOS5 and above..

The solution given:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
if ([app respondsToSelector:@selector(beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)]) {
    backgroundTaskIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (backgroundTaskIdentifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
            {
                // you took too long - clean up what you can, then …
                [app endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifier];
                backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    }];
}
```

Another question is where should I put this code.

Need some guidance on this..

Answer (score 0):

The solution you found in the other answer is good for iOS 4.0 *and above*. It works just fine, and remains [the recommended way](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28) to perform an extended task when moving to the background.

Also, unless you're trying to support iOS 3.x -- which isn't all that advisable anymore -- you don't need the `respondsToSelector` check.

Comment: It gives me an error:"Comparsion between pointer and integer" for this line:backgroundTaskIdentifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

Comment: Either `backgroundTaskIdentifier` shouldn't be declared as a pointer, or you should make sure to dereference it for the comparison. See the aforelinked programming guide, the [`UIApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:) docs, or the Apple sample code the link to for details.